# iOS 9 beta Language ID syntax change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm quite confusing, why in iOS 9 beta the return value of language code is different from iOS 8.4?

Function:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleLanguages")
```

Just set Language to "Simple Chinese" and Region to "China".

In iOS 8.4, return *"zh-Hanz"* but in iOS 9 beta 4 return *"zh-Hanz-CN"*. 
The Language ID syntax is much more like

> "[language designator]-[script designator]-[region designator]".

[Is different with apple document:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW1)

Is it a new rule in iOS 9? Can someone help me to confirm this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It sounds to me like Apple is just enhancing the codes in iOS 9 for certain languages.  Is this for *all* languages or just for "Simple Chinese" (where there might be a different region code at the end, e.g. "TW"?).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, if set a different region get a different region code at the end, e.g. "TW". I have also test English language with different region, and get the same results as "Simple Chinese". It seems if language without a region, iOS 9 add a region at the end than iOS 8, but is it for all languages? I don't know and want to be confirmed.

Comment: Is the `Hanz` in the question meant to be `Hans`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I noticed it too while using
[NSLocale preferredLanguages]

In iOS 9 beta it returned zh-Hans-US ( with region set to US and language to Chinese Simplified ) whereas in iOS 8.4 it used to return zh-Hans only.

So meanwhile I have been using
[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]
This returns the current localization ( zh-hans ) which is without the region post-fix ( -US )

To confirm, iOS 9 adds the region post-fix ( like -US or -CN ) to all of the languages.

Answer (score 3):

You should use componentsFromLocaleIdentifiert to split the locale identifier and find the language code. Like here:

```
+ (NSString*)currentLanguage
{
    NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString* identifier = locale.localeIdentifier;
    NSDictionary* components = [NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:identifier];
    NSLog(@"components:\n%@", components);
    return [components valueForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *allLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [allLanguage objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"The current language is : %@", currentLanguage);
```

iOS 9 Before：returns:language ID.for example："zh-Hans"

iOS 9:returns:Language ID + region ID.for example："zh-Hans-US"

Notice:
1.Don't use the following method to check the current language.

```
if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"])
```

you can use the following method instead：

```
if ([currentLanguage hasPrefix:@"zh-Hans"])
```

Also:If you care about Chinese,you must pay attention to these:

- Simplified Chinese:zh-Hans
- Traditional Chinese:zh-Hant
- Hong Kong Chinese:zh-HK
- Macao Chinese:zh-MO
- Taiwan Chinese:zh-TW
- Singapore Chinese:zh-SG

**Notice:In some case,we have different result,especially when you deal with Chinese.It's a little strange.For example:**

> My mobile phone is:China Mainland/China Telecom/A1533/16GB
>   version.When I choose the language as Taiwan,the region is
>   China,HongKong or Taiwan,the result is "zh-TW",and when you set the
>   region as Not Chinese Region,the language will change to the
>   traditional Chinese.

So please pay more attention to the language especially when you deal with the language Chinese!

You can also check the iOS 9 adaption details here:https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS9AdaptationTips